# Not able to save new data frame after mutate command

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add new column **Petal** which is product of two other columns to the data frame and it works with below code

```
b %>% 
mutate(Petal = Petal.Length * Petal.Width) %>%
head
```

but the problem is when I print `b` after, **Petal** diapears.

I tried also this but it brings error

```
b <- mutate(Petal = Petal.Length*Petal.Width)
```

so, how can I save it?

Comment: You need to assign it to a new object or the old object i.e. `b <- b %>% mutate(Petal = Petal.Length * Petal.Width)` or use the `%<>%` operator from `magrittr` i.e. `library(magrittr); b %<>% mutate(Petal = Petal.Length * Petal.Width)`

Comment: both versions that you suggested work, thank you.

Comment: I don't know if i need to open a new question or not but my question is that I have 150 rows but after I run mutate command only 6 are left, what is the problem?

Comment: Please check the `str(b)`  It must be a printing problem on the console by the `tbl_df` object .  Try `b %>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: b is a data.frame

Comment: `head` prints 6 rows by default.